# CentOS 5.6 expand ext4 partition , have steps but parted shows as ext3

Tags: partition, ext4, parted, resize2fs

I have a Adaptec 5805 HW RAID card with a 6.3 TB RAID-6 array (partitioned via Parted GPT, all of which is formatted as ext4 on CentOS 5.6).

I want to expand this to 7.5GB and from reading these are the steps I've come up with, my question is, do I have the steps right on the linux part, and why is parted showing the partition as ext3 and not as ext4?

**NOTE:** I've read that Parted does not support ext4 yet and man Parted states "ext3 resizing does not currently work with Parted".

I've been able to backup all 6 TB of data on this drive prior to expanding.

1. Verify with Fix Raid array in Adaptec Storage Manager
2. Expand Raid-6 Array in Adaptec Storage Manager

   on Centos 5.6:
3. Unmount target drive/partition
4. Expand partition, keeping the start position the exact same as it is currently - use Sector mode if using parted (but parted says NOT to use Parted for resizing ext3 or ext4)
5. run `resize2fs` (or should I run resize4fs as it's ext4?)
6. remount

Hopefully someone who has resized an ext4 drive over 2TB can chime in and state what they did to successfully resize their mount/partition.  Every guide I've read says to use Parted , but `man parted` says to use `fdisk` (but `fdisk` doesn't work with partitions over 2 TB that need GPT).

So my biggest issues is with the resize partition step of this process as I'm dealing with a 6 TB ext4 partition.

`Parted -l` output (when unit set to Sector):

```
    Model: Adaptec 6tbRD6ada8 (scsi)
    Disk /dev/sdb: 6979GB
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
    Partition Table: gpt

     Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
     1      17.4kB  6979GB  6979GB  ext3         primary
```

`fdisk -l` of target drive:

```
    Disk /dev/sdb: 6979.3 GB, 6979309273088 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 848519 cylinders
    Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
     /dev/sdb1               1      267350  2147483647+  ee  EFI GPT
```

`cfdisk /dev/sdb`:

```
      cfdisk (util-linux 2.13-pre7)

                                                       Disk Drive: /dev/sdb
                                               Size: 6979309273088 bytes, 6979.3 GB
                                      Heads: 255   Sectors per Track: 63   Cylinders: 848519

  Name                 Flags               Part Type          FS Type                     [Label]                   Size (MB)
  sdb1                 NC                   Primary           EFI GPT                                              2199023.26         *
                                            Pri/Log           Free Space                                           4780283.11         *
```

Comment: Seems like you can do this with parted: http://askubuntu.com/questions/115310/how-to-resize-enlarge-grow-a-non-lvm-ext4-partition. You could also try using GParted.